# deployment problem with permission denied while selecting node version

Tags: azure-web-app-service, kudu

From the beginning, I've always had problem using kudu deployment for my node 12 web app.
This time I have `select node version failed` in pipeline logs, but a `Not setting execute permissions for bash` when I access the log details from the link. The worst is that nothing has changed in the code or the pipeline, one day you woke up, and your app doesn't work any more. This is the third time it happens, every time a new version of node is available in the list of available versions. Can someone please point me out THE solution that will work for more than one month please ? I used the default script for node web apps from kudu documentation, just replaced npm with yarn. And using the environment variables `WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION` and `WEBSITE_NPM_DEFAULT_VERSION` in the app configuration. I tried every combination of node version var with or without the npm one, ... nothing works. I really need a long term solution to finally solve this problem, otherwise I think I will move to more stable alternatives. Any help is much appreciated.
An issue that can be related https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/issues/2870#issuecomment-443464291

**EDIT**

this is my .deployment file

```
[config]
command = bash ./scripts/bash/deploy.sh
```

this is my shell file in `scripts/bash/deploy.sh`, as you can see the only difference with the default custom deployment script retrived with the command `kuduscript -y --node`, is yarn instead of npm

```
#!/bin/bash

# ----------------------
# KUDU Deployment Script
# Version: 1.0.17
# ----------------------

# Helpers
# -------

exitWithMessageOnError() {
  if [ ! $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "An error has occurred during web site deployment."
    echo $1
    exit 1
  fi
}

# Prerequisites
# -------------

# Verify node.js installed
hash node 2>/dev/null
exitWithMessageOnError "Missing node.js executable, please install node.js, if already installed make sure it can be reached from current environment."

# Setup
# -----

SCRIPT_DIR="${BASH_SOURCE[0]%\\*}"
SCRIPT_DIR="${SCRIPT_DIR%/*}"
ARTIFACTS=$SCRIPT_DIR/../artifacts
KUDU_SYNC_CMD=${KUDU_SYNC_CMD//\"/}

if [[ ! -n "$DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE" ]]; then
  DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE=$SCRIPT_DIR
fi

if [[ ! -n "$NEXT_MANIFEST_PATH" ]]; then
  NEXT_MANIFEST_PATH=$ARTIFACTS/manifest

  if [[ ! -n "$PREVIOUS_MANIFEST_PATH" ]]; then
    PREVIOUS_MANIFEST_PATH=$NEXT_MANIFEST_PATH
  fi
fi

if [[ ! -n "$DEPLOYMENT_TARGET" ]]; then
  DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=$ARTIFACTS/wwwroot
else
  KUDU_SERVICE=true
fi

if [[ ! -n "$KUDU_SYNC_CMD" ]]; then
  # Install kudu sync
  echo Installing Kudu Sync
  npm install kudusync -g --silent
  exitWithMessageOnError "npm failed"

  if [[ ! -n "$KUDU_SERVICE" ]]; then
    # In case we are running locally this is the correct location of kuduSync
    KUDU_SYNC_CMD=kuduSync
  else
    # In case we are running on kudu service this is the correct location of kuduSync
    KUDU_SYNC_CMD=$APPDATA/npm/node_modules/kuduSync/bin/kuduSync
  fi
fi

# Node Helpers
# ------------

selectNodeVersion() {
  if [[ -n "$KUDU_SELECT_NODE_VERSION_CMD" ]]; then
    SELECT_NODE_VERSION="$KUDU_SELECT_NODE_VERSION_CMD \"$DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE\" \"$DEPLOYMENT_TARGET\" \"$DEPLOYMENT_TEMP\""
    eval $SELECT_NODE_VERSION
    exitWithMessageOnError "select node version failed"

    if [[ -e "$DEPLOYMENT_TEMP/__nodeVersion.tmp" ]]; then
      NODE_EXE=$(cat "$DEPLOYMENT_TEMP/__nodeVersion.tmp")
      exitWithMessageOnError "getting node version failed"
    fi

    if [[ -e "$DEPLOYMENT_TEMP/__npmVersion.tmp" ]]; then
      NPM_JS_PATH=$(cat "$DEPLOYMENT_TEMP/__npmVersion.tmp")
      exitWithMessageOnError "getting npm version failed"
    fi

    if [[ ! -n "$NODE_EXE" ]]; then
      NODE_EXE=node
    fi

    NPM_CMD="\"$NODE_EXE\" \"$NPM_JS_PATH\""
  else
    NPM_CMD=npm
    NODE_EXE=node
  fi
}

##################################################################################################################################
# Deployment
# ----------

echo Handling node.js deployment.

# 1. KuduSync
if [[ "$IN_PLACE_DEPLOYMENT" -ne "1" ]]; then
  "$KUDU_SYNC_CMD" -v 50 -f "$DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE" -t "$DEPLOYMENT_TARGET" -n "$NEXT_MANIFEST_PATH" -p "$PREVIOUS_MANIFEST_PATH" -i ".git;.hg;.deployment;deploy.sh"
  exitWithMessageOnError "Kudu Sync failed"
fi

# 2. Select node version
selectNodeVersion

# 3. Install yarn packages
if [ -e "$DEPLOYMENT_TARGET/package.json" ]; then
  cd "$DEPLOYMENT_TARGET"
  echo "Running yarn install"
  eval yarn install --production=false --network-timeout 1000000
  echo "building dist"
  eval yarn build
  echo "Running migrations"
  eval yarn typeorm:migration:run
  exitWithMessageOnError "yarn failed"
  cd - >/dev/null
fi

##################################################################################################################################
echo "Finished successfully."
```

I set (this time, but I already tried multiple combinations) only the variable `WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION` to `12.18.2`, and I didn't set the `WEBSITE_NPM_DEFAULT_VERSION` variable. This is the output when I try to deploy using git local method, with the command `git push azure master:master`:

```
Enumerating objects: 9, done.
Counting objects: 100% (9/9), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (5/5), 391 bytes | 391.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 5 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: Deploy Async
remote: Updating branch 'master'.
remote: Updating submodules.
remote: Preparing deployment for commit id '79f0842a60'.
remote: Running custom deployment command...
remote: Not setting execute permissions for bash ./scripts/bash/deploy.sh
remote: Running deployment command...
remote: Handling node.js deployment.
remote: Kudu sync from: '/home/site/repository' to: '/home/site/wwwroot'
remote: Ignoring: .deployment
remote: Ignoring: .git
remote: Ignoring: scripts/bash/deploy.sh
remote: Detecting node version spec...
remote: Using appsetting WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION value: 12.18.2
remote: Node.js versions available on the platform are: 8.0.0, 8.1.4, 8.2.1, 8.8.1, 8.9.4, 8.11.4, 8.12.0, 8.15.1, 8.17.0, 9.4.0, 10.1.0, 10.10.0, 10.14.2, 10.21.0, 10.23.0, 12.18.2, 12.19.0, 14.15.0.
remote: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/opt/nodejs/12.18.2/npm.txt'
remote: Resolved to version 12.18.2
remote: Detecting npm version spec...
remote: An error has occurred during web site deployment.
remote: select node version failed
remote: Deployment Logs : 'https://***.scm.azurewebsites.net/newui/jsonviewer?view_url=/api/deployments/79f0842a60c7fe25af603fe673868789272923e3/log'
To https://***.scm.azurewebsites.net:443/kiwi-prod-appservice.git
   cdc1c91..79f0842  master -> master
```

When I click on the link to see log details:

```
[
    "0" :
    {
        "details_url" : null,
        "id" : "660d4119-1437-494a-a97b-5af7244afd58",
        "log_time" : "2020-12-22T04:58:51.7786621Z",
        "message" : "Updating branch 'master'.",
        "type" : 0
    }
    ,
    "1" :
    {
        "details_url" : null,
        "id" : "bca90e55-fc4c-40c4-91bd-337a0e3df515",
        "log_time" : "2020-12-22T04:58:53.3322101Z",
        "message" : "Updating submodules.",
        "type" : 0
    }
    ,
    "2" :
    {
        "details_url" : null,
        "id" : "bfc59c6f-e3ad-4bbd-afb5-bda11bec9771",
        "log_time" : "2020-12-22T04:58:53.3779506Z",
        "message" : "Preparing deployment for commit id '79f0842a60'.",
        "type" : 0
    }
    ,
    "3" :
    {
        "details_url" : null,
        "id" : "92219cc6-d58f-4988-9ec5-c1fd109c0986",
        "log_time" : "2020-12-22T04:58:53.4866308Z",
        "message" : "Running custom deployment command...",
        "type" : 0
    }
    ,
    "4" :
    {
        "details_url" : null,
        "id" : "f61aa2f5-8d77-4d3b-b328-3ab1fc69bf33",
        "log_time" : "2020-12-22T04:58:53.51928Z",
        "message" : "Not setting execute permissions for bash ./scripts/bash/deploy.sh",
        "type" : 0
    }
    ,
    "5" :
    {
        "details_url" : "https://***.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/deployments/79f0842a60c7fe25af603fe673868789272923e3/log/3ed28b72-4514-4c87-8d6a-006c09150754",
        "id" : "3ed28b72-4514-4c87-8d6a-006c09150754",
        "log_time" : "2020-12-22T04:58:53.5555321Z",
        "message" : "Running deployment command...",
        "type" : 2
    }
]
```

Comment: We cannot reproduce the phenomenon you described. You can tell us what you have done and how to reproduce the problem. Tell us these steps in detail so that you can better solve the problem. Or directly raise a support ticket for help, Microsoft Engineer will help you check the log.

Comment: @JasonPan I edited the post and put all the details. Thank you in advance

Comment: also, from the kudu debug bash console, when I type `node -v` I get `v14.15.0`. Is that the only version for linux based containers ?

Comment: same error trying to deploy on a newly created slot

Answer (score 0):

solved (for now) after commenting the `SELECT_NODE_VERSION` command

```
# SELECT_NODE_VERSION="$KUDU_SELECT_NODE_VERSION_CMD \"$DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE\" \"$DEPLOYMENT_TARGET\" \"$DEPLOYMENT_TEMP\""
# eval $SELECT_NODE_VERSION
# exitWithMessageOnError "select node version failed"
```

because the error was always triggered. I also had to use `npm` instead of `yarn`, because the node version used by yarn wasn't the correct one